# How do you kill a repeated timer when proper results are found

Tags: ios, xcode, webview, nstimer

I have a NS Timer Firing within a web view load that looks for information on the page.  I then do some manipulations to the page setting checkboxes etc which bring in some AJAX functions which as people may know does not fire the webviewloaded method.  In short I would like to create a time that checks every 5 seconds to check to for a specific part that only occurs when the proper information is loaded.  This is fine I can do this, but I don't know how to stop the NSTIMER as all the examples here do not show a parameter being passed into the function.

currently I have

```
   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(fcheckForEditFinished) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void) fcheckForEditFinished
{
//Would like to kill timer at this point. 
}
```

Thanks Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation of `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval%3atarget%3aselector%3auserInfo%3arepeats%3a) says this:

> *aSelector*
>   The message to send to *target* when the timer fires. The
>   selector must have the following signature:
>   `- (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer*)theTimer`
>   The timer passes itself as the argument to this method.

And you can "kill" a timer by sending it the `invalidate` message.  So change `fcheckForEditFinished` to `fcheckForEditFinished:` like this:

```
- (void)fcheckForEditFinished:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    if (checkForEdit()) {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

The timer will automatically pass itself as the parameter of `fcheckForEditFinished:`.  Make sure you add the colon to the selector in your call to `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:...` too.

Comment: Do I have to pass something through in my selector?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but I believe the answer is no.

Comment: typically wouldn't you pass the object into the method?  again i'm from the windows world but if you have a method

-(void) myfn:(NSSTring *) mystring
{
}

and you call said method wouldn't it be myfn(@"some string");  I do not see that being done here

Comment: Outstanding help sir.  I appreciate the time.

Comment: Additional Quick question I get SigAboprt


Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AttendanceWizardViewController fcheckForEditFinished]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68893e0'

Comment: My guess is you didn't change `@selector(fcheckForEditFinished)` to `@selector(fcheckForEditFinished:)` where you create the timer.  Note the trailing colon; that's part of the selector.  Or you're sending the `fcheckForEditFinished` message somewhere else and you need to change it to `fcheckForEditFinished:`.

Comment: Shoot missed that line in your answer that was already there.  Again, I appreciate it immensely.  Best -- Kevin